Problem in installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status
I'm using

install.packages("recipes")

or

install.packages("recipes", dependencies = TRUE)

i got this error

Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string (:4:36)
Execution halted Warning in install.packages :   installation of
package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status

help me to slove the error

What operating system are you using?
